# Parsing a 2D array in handlebars.js

Tags: html, json, handlebars.js

Am having the following JSON data in my hand, I need to create a table, but the data is dynamic(both row header and column header & cell values).

JSON structure as follows,

```
{        
    "data": {
        "vertical_header": [
            "football",
            "hockey"
        ],
        "horizontal_header": [
            "China",
            "Brazil",
            "Australia"
        ],
        "researchDetails": [
            {
                "country": "brazil",
                "game": "hockey",
                "player": "Mr.r"
            },
            {
                "country": "china",
                "game": "hockey",
                "player": "Mr.X"
            },
            {
                "country": "china",
                "game": "football",
                "player": "Mr.Y"
            },
            {
                "country": "china",
                "game": "football",
                "player": "Mr.Z"
            },
            {
                "country": "brazil",
                "game": "football",
                "player": "Mr.M"
            },
            {
                "country": "brazil",
                "game": "football",
                "player": "Mr.E"
            }    
        ]
    }
}
```

The following is the table structure, I have to parse such JSON to construct a dynamic table like this using handlebars template.  The headers are also dynamic, I have to create an array (2D/3D) so that I can construct the following,

```
<html>
</body>
<table border="1">
        <tr><th/><th>hockey</th><th>football</th></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="2">china</td><td>Mr.X</td><td>Mr.Y</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td>Mr.Z</td></tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="2">brazil</td><td>Mr.r</td><td>Mr.M</td></tr>
        <tr><td ></td><td>Mr.e</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Australia</td><td></td><td/></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Formatting the source code properly reveals... your JSON and HTML are both broken! http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @will-hart : Now edited both my html & json

Comment: If it is even possible, this would require a lot of manipulation of data in handlebars to get the table displayed correctly. Doing this in a template is usually a sign of poor design.  

I would recommend setting up the data better server side if possible - perhaps getting lists of player names grouped by country and game.